# How to opent text file for editing, ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, text

The page has link to the text file placed somewhere in the network. If I click the link the file will be opened in the browser without the opportunity to edit it. How to do that user can click and open it in his/her favorite text editor?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are trying to do is to edit the contents of the TEXT file then why not display the contents in a TextBox and let users update the contents and then save it.

Answer (score 1):

they'll need to download it as an attachment

```
string fileName = "text.txt";
string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/" + fileName);
Response.Clear();

Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.WriteFile(filePath);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Comment: Hmmm it works, really file can be opened in the editor, but as for as it's just attachment user cannot edit it, then close and save the changes in the primary file. I need the following process: user clicks the link, browser allows him/her to open file in editor, then click save (in editor) and file will be saved on the network.